# Renewed brake pads

Tags: brakes, service, terminology

I am new to the automotive world and especially in services. I did some research on some things, but others I cannot find definite answer.

> I bought a car which has had "**renewed brake pads and discs**" but I do not really
>   understand the word "renewed", tried to translate it from German
>   (Erneuert). Does this mean the brake pads were replaced or that they
>   have been modified somehow to last some longer?

Because my car has a system that traces when the next service is needed. And the service interval for brakes has been reseted prior buying the used car. If renew means that they are just "refurbished" or in even more stupid writin "cleaned", I would need to know how long is the actual mileage / time that I can go without replacing them.

Thanks.

Comment: Car model? If it's German >> Mercedes/VW/Audi, many of these have a sensor (just a wire) that goes in each brake pad that wears through, when the pads get low enough, setting off a "replace pads" warning on your dash. If equipped, that indicator is far more useful since it essentially measures pad thickness, not distance driven.

Comment: It is German, but not one of the mentioned. It is BMW F30 318dA year of production 2013. I cannot find it listed amongst the options of the car, do you know if this BMW has this sensor?

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's the one I missed ;) from the talk I'm reading around forums, it does appear the 3 series is equipped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

German here.

The word "erneuert" always means that something has been replaced. The only remarkable exception is a "runderneuerter Reifen" i.e. a retreaded tire, though... even here something has been replaced.

The term "überholt" literally means "overhauled" or "refurbished"

Further more, mechanics here mostly just replace parts instead of fixing them, which is especially true for critical components like the brakes. I read here on MS.SE for the first time that rotors are resurfaced.

> Erneuert wurden Oel und Oelfilter, Microfilter, Bremsscheiben vorn und Bremsbeläge vorn und hinten.

means

> Oil, oil filter, pollen filter, rotors (front) and pads (front & rear) have been replaced.

Comment: Thank you sweber! This is the entire statement: Erneuert wurden Oel und Oelfilter, Microfilter, Bremsscheiben vorn und Bremsbeläge vorn und hinten.

Comment: Our guidance when I was a mechanic was this

Remove and Renew = remove old parts, fit new parts
Remove and Replace = service old parts and put them back on...

confusing I know.

Answer (score 2):

Renewing is typically a term used to state that something has been returned to "new" condition. In your case, this would lead me to believe the pads and rotors were replaced with new.

Only problem is, there is no way for us (this site) to know for sure. You would have to ask the person you purchased it from what they mean. If they have an invoice for the service, it would tell you.

Reference - [Renewing disc-brake pads](https://www.howacarworks.com/brakes/renewing-disc-brake-pads)

Comment: Thank you Charlie for your answer. I know it's a bit on a stupid side of questions, I was just hopping if it's maybe some "mechanical terminology / slang" and you guys would know about it. Otherwise, by merely just translating it or reading it word by word, it is indeed hard to tell what he means. Will try to get direct answer. Because service interval was reset.